# Avoid proxy blocking Etherpad Lite

Tags: web-services, apache, virtualhost, reverse-proxy, etherpad

I've set up an Etherpad Lite on my Apache server, the address is something like http://example.com:9001 and I wish to access it from my university but a proxy is blocking the port.
On the wiki of the software, a technique known as ["reverse proxy"](https://github.com/Pita/etherpad-lite/wiki/How-to-put-Etherpad-Lite-behind-a-reverse-Proxy) is explained to circumvent that, and make the pad accessible from an address like http://pad.exemple.com or http://example.com/pad but unfortunately it's not working and I've tried many different combinations.
I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong or if there any easier technique to get what I want.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google points to https://github.com/Pita/etherpad-lite/wiki/How-to-put-Etherpad-Lite-behind-a-reverse-Proxy
where it is explained how to set up a reverse proxy. You should follow the instructions for Apache.

Comment: Thanks but like I said in my description, I already followed these instructions and it didn't work. I'm looking for alternatives.

Comment: Right. I think you need to 1) explain exactly how you followed the instructions, and 2) perhaps move this question to either of the "Support forums". As I've understood, stackoverflow is for knowledge/research and superuser (or some webmaster forum) is for practical questions that consider exactly how you've installed your software etc.
I'm running several reverse proxies, using apache2, nginx, thttpd (throttling), cherokee and never had any problems other than my own mistakes and typos in config files. Maybe post your configs, but careful to anonymize. Type "service apache reload" much?

Answer (score 0):

You should expose more what you have done (configuration used). Bad description implies bad answer.

So official documentation is at https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite/wiki/How-to-put-Etherpad-Lite-behind-a-reverse-Proxy